# How do I retrieve query parameters in a Spring Boot controller?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

I am developing a project using Spring Boot. I've a controller which accepts *GET* requests.

Currently I'm accepting requests to the following kind of URLs:

> http://localhost:8888/user/data/002

but I want to accept requests using *query parameters*:

> http://localhost:8888/user?data=002

Here's the code of my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/data/{itemid}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
item getitem(@PathVariable("itemid") String itemid) {   
    item i = itemDao.findOne(itemid);              
    String itemname = i.getItemname();
    String price = i.getPrice();
    return i;
}
```

Comment: [`@RequestParam`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html) (good starting point: [the official guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html))

Comment: > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201441/how-do-i-retrieve-query-parameters-in-a-spring-boot-controller

Answer (score 305, accepted):

Use **@RequestParam**

```
@RequestMapping(value="user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Item getItem(@RequestParam("data") String itemid){

    Item i = itemDao.findOne(itemid);              
    String itemName = i.getItemName();
    String price = i.getPrice();
    return i;
}
```

Comment: then what is the URL of this method can you please tell ?   What should i have to change

Comment: sorry bro this URL is not working localhost:8888/user?data=001   I have enter this URL

Comment: Remove **value="/"** from the request mapping annotation. Btw this is really poor design. If you're going to access an item for a user then the rest way would be **user/items/{itemId}**.

Comment: Using **@RequestParam** as `public @ResponseBody item getitem(@RequestParam("data") String itemid){` requires **data** query parameter to be always present. Instead if you use it this way `public @ResponseBody item getitem(@RequestParam Map<String, String> queryParameters){` , it makes **data** to be optional

Comment: @SampathSurineni it should be `Map<String, String[]> queryParameters` instead.

Comment: @samsri, or just use `@RequestParam(name = "data", required = false)`

Comment: Latest looks like: `If the method parameter is Map<String, String> or MultiValueMap<String, String> and a parameter name is not specified, then the map parameter is populated with all request parameter names and values.`

Answer (score 34):

While the accepted answer by afraisse is absolutely correct in terms of using `@RequestParam`, I would further suggest to use an Optional<> as you cannot always ensure the right parameter is used. Also, if you need an Integer or Long just use that data type to avoid casting types later on in the DAO.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/data", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
Item getItem(@RequestParam("itemid") Optional<Integer> itemid) { 
    if( itemid.isPresent()){
         Item i = itemDao.findOne(itemid.get());              
         return i;
     } else ....
}
```

Comment: where did you get Optional from?

Comment: @JoeyGough introduced in Java 8. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html

Comment: It's a bad idea to put Optional in parameter. Don't use Optional in parameters. For this problem, you can use required = false.

Comment: @slim why is it a bad idea to use Optional?

Comment: @hemanth5636, because you can have 3 possible values and not 2 ... (https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-3553)

Comment: But in this case Spring MVC will always populate it.  So it will never be null.

Answer (score 19):

To accept both `@PathVariable` and `@RequestParam` in the same `/user` endpoint:

```
@GetMapping(path = {"/user", "/user/{data}"})
public void user(@PathVariable(required=false,name="data") String data,
                 @RequestParam(required=false) Map<String,String> qparams) {
    qparams.forEach((a,b) -> {
        System.out.println(String.format("%s -> %s",a,b));
    }
  
    if (data != null) {
        System.out.println(data);
    }
}
```

Testing with curl:

- curl 'http://localhost:8080/user/books'
- curl 'http://localhost:8080/user?book=ofdreams&name=nietzsche'

Comment: what if you want to pass negatives, like `&name!=nietzsche` ?

Comment: You can simply introduce another request parameter and put the unwanted name there :)

Answer (score 8):

To accept both Path Variable and query Param in the same endpoint:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello/{name}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String sayHi(
            @PathVariable("name") String name, 
            @RequestBody Topic topic,
            //@RequestParam(required = false, name = "s") String s, 
            @RequestParam Map<String, String> req) {
        
        return "Hi "+name +" Topic : "+ topic+" RequestParams : "+req;
    }
```

URL looks like : http://localhost:8080/hello/testUser?city=Pune&Pin=411058&state=Maha

Answer (score 5):

In Spring boot: 2.1.6, you can use like below:

```
    @GetMapping("/orders")
    @ApiOperation(value = "retrieve orders", response = OrderResponse.class, responseContainer = "List")
    public List<OrderResponse> getOrders(
            @RequestParam(value = "creationDateTimeFrom", required = true) String creationDateTimeFrom,
            @RequestParam(value = "creationDateTimeTo", required = true) String creationDateTimeTo,
            @RequestParam(value = "location_id", required = true) String location_id) {

        // TODO...

        return response;
```

@ApiOperation is an annotation that comes from Swagger api, It is used for documenting the apis.

Comment: `required = true` by default

Answer (score 4):

I was interested in this as well and came across some examples on the Spring Boot site.

```
   // get with query string parameters e.g. /system/resource?id="rtze1cd2"&person="sam smith" 
// so below the first query parameter id is the variable and name is the variable
// id is shown below as a RequestParam
    @GetMapping("/system/resource")
    // this is for swagger docs
    @ApiOperation(value = "Get the resource identified by id and person")
    ResponseEntity<?> getSomeResourceWithParameters(@RequestParam String id, @RequestParam("person") String name) {

        InterestingResource resource = getMyInterestingResourc(id, name);
        logger.info("Request to get an id of "+id+" with a name of person: "+name);

        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(resource, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

[See here also](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-param)