# Get values with Spring Boot from http link

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-rest

I want to get the values from this http link:

```
https://www.test.com/notification?con=41280440000097&dp=1232&type=single

https://www.test.com/notification?con=41280440000097&sec=1232
```

I tried to implement this Spring code:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/v1/notification")
    public String handleNotifications(@RequestParam("notification") String itemid) {
        // parse here the values
    return "result";
    }
```

But how I can parse the http link and get the values for example in ArrayList of HashMap?

Comment: This is pretty basic stuff. Did you do any research?

Comment: I tried but I haven't find anything working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I retrieve query parameters in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201441/how-do-i-retrieve-query-parameters-in-spring-boot)

Comment: I updated my post. But how I can get the exact keys and values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your controller method should be like this with `RequestParam` to get the values from request, you can make `RequestParam optional with`required=false`and you can set default value also`(@RequestParam(value = "i", defaultValue = "10") int i`

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/v1/notification")
public String handleNotifications(@RequestParam(value="con", required=false) String itemid, @RequestParam(value="dp", required=false) String dp, @RequestParam(value="type", required=false) String type ) 
    {
     // you can use all these values directly in this method
    // parse here the values
return "result";
}
```

Comment: Thanks but what if I have 2 keys and values? is there other way to parse them?

Comment: you me two values for one key `con=41280440000097,1234566&dp=1232&type=single` like this?

Comment: What if required param is not found? Error will be thrown?

Comment: it will null, no error, if you don't want null set default value

Comment: Can you extend the post please. Also is there any security that I can add?

Comment: can you please be more specific ? what do you mean by security ?

Comment: For injecting very long string.

Comment: Are there any Spring filters?

Comment: it depends on requirement

Comment: Can you post some example? For example I want to limit all Strings to 10 symbols

Comment: read this artical https://www.javaquery.com/2018/02/passing-and-validating-requestparam-in.html . if you still have doubts then let me know