# Spring: How can I get value from uri?

Tags: spring-boot

How can the **callbackFacebook** function get the value of code from the uri?

uri = http://localhost:8081/callback?code=AQDNm6hezKdTsId5k4oXKNo

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/callback?{code}", method = RequestMethod.GET)

public String callbackFacebook(Model model, @PathVariable(name = "code") String code) {

    System.out.println(code);
    return "login";
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I retrieve query parameters in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201441/how-do-i-retrieve-query-parameters-in-spring-boot)

Comment: After `?`, its query, not path.  
Yon can find out syntax of URI from here. : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL. .

Answer (score 1):

Try this. `code` is a *query parameter* judging by your URL, not a path variable. Path variables are a part of the path itself (i.e. if your URL was something like `/{code}/callback`, then code is a PathVariable).

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/callback", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String callbackFacebook(Model model, @RequestParam(value = "code") String code) {
        System.out.println(code);
        return "login";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your URL is `http://localhost:8081/callback?code=AQDNm6hezKdTsId5k4oXKNo` then it is case of request parameters so the method will be like below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/callback", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String callbackFacebook(Model model, @RequestParam(value = "code") String code) {
        return "login";
}
```

If your URL is `http://localhost:8081/callback/AQDNm6hezKdTsId5k4oXKNo` then then it is case of path variables method will be like below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/callback/{code}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String callbackFacebook(Model model, @PathVariable(value = "code") String code) {
        return "login";
}
```

Refer [requestparam-vs-pathvariable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715811/requestparam-vs-pathvariable) for better clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I will explain 2 ways.

1-If it is added in the session in somewhere in the project as attribute,You can get it like this :

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/callback?{code}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String callbackFacebook(Model model, @PathVariable(name = "code") String code,HttpServletRequest request) {

        String code1 = request.getSession().getAttribute("code").toString();


        return "login";
    }
```

example output : AQDNm6hezKdTsId5k4oXKNo

2-You can directly get URL.But then you need to parse URL.Because all URL is coming.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/callback?{code}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String callbackFacebook(Model model, @PathVariable(name = "code") String code,HttpServletRequest request) {

        StringBuffer requestURL = request.getRequestURL();

        return "login";
    }
```

example output : http://localhost:8081/callback?code=AQDNm6hezKdTsId5k4oXKNo