# Adding parameter to rest API fetch method (ReactJS > Spring boot)

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, post, fetch, rest

I simply want to send a value to my rest api in a fetch method but can't seem to get it to work.
This is what I have currently:

React:

```
getFloorplans() {
        fetch('/api/ssid')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(message => {
                this.setState({
                    floorplan: message[0]
                })
            });

        fetch('/api/ssid', {
            method: "POST",

            //make sure to serialize your JSON body
            value: {ssid: this.state.SSID}
        })
            .then( (response => response.json()
                .then(message => {
                    console.log(message);
                })
        ))};
```

Spring boot rest api:

```
@RestController
public class FloorplanController {
    //Floorplan floorplan = new Floorplan();

    @RequestMapping("/api/ssid")
    public void someMethod(@RequestParam String value) {
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

This is the error I'm currently getting:
[image]

Comment: You should use `@PostMapping("/api/ssid")` if you are performing a POST request, the HTTP method is not specified at the moment.
Second thing, I don't know a lot of React, but if you are sending your value as a JSON body you should use `@RequestBody` in your method.

Comment: Also, I think you have to use `body` instead of `value`, as that is what `fetch` expects: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: And how do I then get the data from the body in my controller?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Spring but you should have some request parameter to where extract the body @Dylan75

Answer (score 0):

The exception is telling you that you are missing the request parameter. That's mean that value for `@RequestParam String value` in your controller is missing. The request should look like this `http://yourhost/api/ssid?value=somevalue`

Answer (score 0):

You should set headers, and params in body.

```js
fetch('/api/ssid', {
     method: "POST",
     headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
     },
     body: {ssid: this.state.SSID}
})
```

Comment: This only confirms what data you're sending but I think the problem lies in my controller but I don't know how to extract the body data there

Comment: Refer this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201441/how-do-i-retrieve-query-parameters-in-spring-boot