# How to pass url as String @pathVariable in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, url

Here's the method I've defined:

```
@GetMapping("/lr/{requester}/{url}/{col}")
    public ResponseEntity<TrainParams> trainUsingLR(
            @PathVariable("requester") String requester,
            @PathVariable("url") String url,
            @PathVariable("col") int col,
            @RequestBody List<String> features)
```

How do I pass an url to the url parameters?

What I've tried:

1. http://localhost:8080/api/ai/lr/0/https%3A%2F%2Fres.cloudinary.com%2Fdoa0jsihz%2Fraw%2Fupload%2Fv1683809593%2Fgr9kzey0yovto2safaah/9. (received 400)
2. http://localhost:8080/api/ai/lr/0/https://res.cloudinary.com/doa0jsihz/raw/upload/v1683809593/gr9kzey0yovto2safaah/9 (received 404).

Note that I've added the request body and succeeded to send request with a random string as "url", What's the right way here?

Answer (score 0):

consider using @RequestParam instead of @PathVariable

```
@GetMapping("/lr/{requester}/{col}")
public ResponseEntity<TrainParams> trainUsingLR(
        @PathVariable("requester") String requester,
        @RequestParam("url") Optional<String> url,
        @PathVariable("col") int col,
        @RequestBody List<String> features)
```

although you can use @RequestParam("url") String url, it is recommended that you use requestParam as a parametrized  Optional

when you open /lr/whatever-requester/your-col?url="your_url_string_here" string is passed to your trainUsingLR method as a RequestParam

you can learn more about request params and passing strings in this thread [how to retrieve query parameters in spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201441/how-do-i-retrieve-query-parameters-in-a-spring-boot-controller)